# Table always on next page

Tags: tables

I am writing on a document where I often have the situation that a table is at the end of a page, but then Latex puts the table on the next page. Now the problem is: The text that is supposed to be AFTER(!) the table appears on the preceding page, as there is apparently not enough space for the table. This is of course an awful situation.

Therefore, I either want to have this space on the preceding page left blank and continue with my table on the next page or I want to split my table into pieces (but not manually, as I would then have to adjust this too frquently then)

Does anybody have an idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the problem is that this occurs only at the end of a page, so I would have to include my whole code, but I will just add some text and a table in order to make the point...just a moment

Comment: Use the `H` option of the `float` package as in: `\begin{table}[H] ... \end{table}`

Comment: @MaartenDhondt thank you, this solved my problem.

Comment: `table`s are floats. If you don't want the table to move, just use e.g. `center` perhaps combined with the `captionof` package.

Comment: Note that the reason figures and tables float in traditional typesetting is to allow the typesetter flexibility to avoid the large spaces that are inevitable if you use `[H]`. the reason they have numbered captions is so that you can refer to them without assuming that they are at a fixed position relative to the text.